# In Spring JPA, how do I efficiently retrieve a specific record from a child table?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have the following tables

```
One Teacher to Many Student

Teacher
id (pk)

Student
id (pk)
teacher_id (fk)
name (string)
```

And with Spring, I have an entity for `Teacher` and a corresponding `TeacherRepository` , and the same for `Student`.

With JPA, how would I retrieve a `Student` object using a `teacher.id` and `student.name`?

I'd be able to do this using SQL statements with native query, but I'd want to do this maintaining object relations.

For example, with `id` and `name` as input, I might achieve this like so:

```
Teacher teacher = teacherRepository.findBy(id);
Set<Student> students= teacher.getStudents();
for (Student s : students) {
  if (s.getName() == name)
    return s;
}
```

But the problem with that is that `findBy` would not be doing a `select` command with a `where Student.name=name`. What's the JPA way that would produce a SQL query that fetches the specific object?

Answer (score 0):

To find JPA entities by their fields you could add a method to the interface of the repository, JPA will generate an SQL query based on the method name

For example to find an unique student by teacherId and name you could write

```
public Strudent getByNameAndTeacherId(String name, Long teacherId)
```

if the value is nullable use `find` instead of `get`

```
public Strudent? findByNameAndTeacherId(String name, Long teacherId)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries